# Removing whole directories in Github

Tags: github, hierarchy

I apologize if this seems like a newbie question, but I'm having some issues navigating through github. I understand the essentials of committing, pushing, peeling etc, but for some reason I can't figure out a few other essentials. If you could take a look at this link it's the GH repo I'm speaking of: https://github.com/AustinTice/JobInterviewAlgorithms . I have pushed new code to the file in the FizzBuzz directory, however the Algorithms/FizzBuzz directory and its containing folders are still on the remote repo although not on my local repo. I just need to know how to delete those directories, and how to essentially get better at rearranging the hierarchies of my repos.

In case clarification is needed, what I'm trying to do in the repo is have [Name of Algorithm] > [Language used to solve] > [Solution] and I need to know how to delete the whole directories, because I'm having some issues.

Comment: Have you committed the repo after deleting the `Algorithms/FizzBuzz` ?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the folder from finder and it isn't even on my local files anymore, but when I committed the new `FizzBuzz` folder it didn't delete the old `Algorithms/FizzBuzz` when I committed.

Comment: I have raised a PR for the same, can you check if it solves your issue. I will update my answer with the steps.

Comment: Awesome I saw that! Thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the folder, all you need to do is stage the changed and commit.

`rm -rf Algorithms`

`git add <changed files>`

`git commit -m <commit message>`

Once done, you can push the commit to the remote repository and the changes will be reflected on `Github`.

`git push origin master`

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I did delete it from my local repo and pushed it, but when I did it kept the old directory `Algorithms/FizzBuzz` and also the new `FizzBuzz` Directory

Answer (score -1):

you should be able to delete the remote branch with following command

`git push origin --delete Algorithms/FizzBuzz`